How to enable ECC in bios for MSI B350 gaming plus
In the motherboard specification, there is nothing about motherboard supports only NON ECC ram, or it don't support ECC ram.
Is there any way, I can enable or use ECC RAM for MSI B350 gaming plus motherboard.
Can someone help me.

The motherboard and BIOS doesn't really have any stake in whether ECC works or not. It only depends on the CPU you have and the RAM modules you have. If they both support ECC then ECC will automatically be working. Sometimes the BIOS has an ECC toggle which affects CPUs with optional ECC support (like consumer CPUs that make no guarantees about stability with it enabled)

Not entirely true. While the chip must have some level of ECC support, the motherboard must also provide some level of ECC support as well. There are motherboards for both Intel and AMD that will take ECC-enabled chips (e.g. Xeons and Ryzen) but will not work with ECC RAM. While the motherboard isn't doing much in terms of providing ECC support, not every motherboard will do that. Ryzen famously doesn't support ECC RAM, but it doesn't lock it out does enable motherboard vendors ECC, even if it's unsupported.

According to this site this MB do not support ECC: http://findhard.ru/en/motherboards/model?id=6400&m=msi-b350-gaming-plus

@RomeoNinov, I found this motherboad support ECC ram https://webapi.adata.com/compatibility-search/uk?brand=MSI&model=B350%20GAMING%20PLUS&platform=all

Firstly, here is a complete list of compatible memories supported by your motherboard. Is your RAM model/make included in this list.
Secondly, if there is nothing in the documentation/specification of the motherboard, it simply means the BIOS does not support it. For some of the supported/unsupported motherboards, ECC is not exposed in the bios. In such case, the best bet could be just replace the RAM physically to see if it works.
